# Three dimensions to two dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the data set in a numpy array with 506 rows and two columns. But when i try to fit any model on it I am getting dimensions error. `Value error: Found array with dim 3.Estimator expected<=2`

```
Array([[[ 6.718 ,19.1]],
       [[ 5.875 ,20.2]],
.....,
```

Can some help to convert as below

```
Col 1.  Col2
6.718.  19.1
5.875.  20.2
Etc
```

I tried by exciting this code as well, `x.transpose(2,0,1).reshape(3,-1)` but it didn't work.
Thank you

Comment: My issue has been resolved. Thanks alot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using:

```
x = x.reshape(2, 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

I tried this,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x=np.array([[8,9],[2,3]])

pd.DataFrame(np.reshape(x,(2,2)),columns=['Col1','Col2'])
```

**output**

```
   Col1 Col2
0   8   9
1   2   3
```